# Error: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, express.js

Estou recebendo este erro no Oracle.

> Error: ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Ao executar o código abaixo que o erro é apresentado, gostaria de saber como resolvo este problema em Node.js.

O campo CONFIG é um CLOB e não LONG.

```
oracle.getConnection('Pool', function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            if (cb) return cb(err);
            else throw new Error({ err: err, err2: 'Expected a callback' });
        }
        oracle.fetchAsString = [oracle.CLOB];

        var a = conn.execute("UPDATE USERS SET USERS.NAME = :NAME, USERS.CONFIG = :CONFIG, WHERE EXISTS (SELECT AUTENTICA.LOGIN_NAME FROM AUTENTICA WHERE USERS.NAME = AUTENTICA.LOGIN_NAME) AND USERS.ID = :ID",
['teste', 'blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah', 1],
{ outFormat: oracle.OBJECT }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                if (cb) {
                    doRelease(conn)
                    return cb(err, null, null, null);
                } else {
                    doRelease(conn)
                    throw new Error('Expected callback function');
                }
            }

            if (result.rowsAffected != undefined) {
                // all data is loaded so we can commit it 
                conn.commit(function (err) {
                    if (err) console.error(err.message);
                    // conn.close(function(err) { if (err) console.error(err); });
                    doRelease(conn)
                });

                data = result.rows ? result.rows : [];

                cb(err, data);

            } else {
                data = result.rows ? result.rows : [];

                cb(err, data);
                doRelease(conn);
            }




        });


    });
```

Comment: Qual o tipo da coluna ID da tabela USERS? Parece que está sendo passado Long e ele não está aceitando. A coluna CONFIG também é varchar?

Comment: A coluna ID é NUMBER(10,0) e a CONFIG é CLOB.. Acho que o problema é a CONFIG que ele entende LONG de vez de CLOB...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156019/ora-01461-can-bind-a-long-value-only-for-insert-into-a-long-column-occurs-when
acho que é o mesmo caso seu
Lista de restrições:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00201